# Parsing A log file into print lines with Java

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I am trying to parse a text file that I converted to a string already.
The text I am trying to parse(This changes every time its generated) but always has 1 or more of the sections(Errors, Warnings, Compliance, Instructional) these lines Start with "Errors", "Warnings", "Compliance" or "Instructional".

Here is a text example:

```
Errors - This section contains errors
The cake is a lie 
All things have endings
Twinkies are back
Warnings - This contains warnings
Show me the money
Metric > Imperial
food for thought
derp derp derp
Compliance- This contains compliance issues
Space is disease and danger wrapped in darkness and silence.
Khaaaaaaaaaaan!
Instructional - Contains Instructional Issues
I'm a doctor, not an escalator.
```

I need to test each line

Psudo Code:

```
boolean E = false;
boolean W = false;
boolean C = false;
boolean I = false;
boolean Skip5 = false;

For each line in the stringFromTextFile{
Skip5 = false;
if the line starts with "Errors"
    E = true;
    W = false;
    C = false;
    I = false;
    Skip5 = true;//start over with next line
if the line starts with "Warnings"
    E = false;
    W = true;
    C = false;
    I = false;
    Skip5 = true;//start over with next line
if the line starts with "Compliance"
    E = false;
    W = false;
    C = true;
    I = false;
    Skip5 = true;//start over with next line
if the line starts with "Instructional" 
    E = false;
    W = false;
    C = false;
    I = true;
    Skip5 = true;//start over with next line 

//Step 5
if(!Skip5){
if(I)
    println "Instructional " + currentLine;
if(E)
    println "Error " + currentLine;
if(W)
    println "Warning " + currentLine;
if(C)
    println "Compliance " + currentLine;
}
//End Step 5
}//end for each
```

Results example that Im trying to get from the above text:

```
Error The cake is a lie 
Error All things have endings
Error Twinkies are back
Warning Show me the money
Warning Metric > Imperial
Warning food for thought
Warning derp derp derp
Compliance Space is disease and danger wrapped in darkness and silence.
Compliance Khaaaaaaaaaaan!
Instructional I'm a doctor, not an escalator.
```

Thanks For any help! Please let me know if what im looking for in unclear. I dont have much experiance with parsing strings and any help I can get.

Comment: Did you try Regular Expressions?

Comment: The problem I had with reg ex is that each line does not start with for example "Errors". It alternates. Could you possibly show me an example of what you had in mind?

Comment: so you can simply take with regex : ^((Error|Warning|Compliance).+) you can put any word which you want to find

Comment: The problem is each word will create a different even like the example text above.

Comment: Got it. Posted what I did

Answer (score 0):

```
String parsedText = output.toString();

        boolean E = false;
        boolean W = false;
        boolean C = false;
        boolean I = false;
        boolean Skip5 = false;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(parsedText);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
          String line = scanner.nextLine();
          Skip5 = false;
          if (line.startsWith("Errors")){
              E = true;
              W = false;
              C = false;
              I = false;
              Skip5 = true;//start over with next line
          }
          if(line.startsWith("Warnings")){
              E = false;
              W = true;
              C = false;
              I = false;
              Skip5 = true;//start over with next line
          }
          if(line.startsWith("Compliance")){
              E = false;
              W = false;
              C = true;
              I = false;
              Skip5 = true;//start over with next line
          }
          if(line.startsWith("Instructional")){ 
              E = false;
              W = false;
              C = false;
              I = true;
              Skip5 = true;//start over with next line 
          }
          //Step 5
          if(!Skip5){
              if(I){
                  System.out.println("Instructional " + line.toString()); 
              }
              if(E){
                  System.out.println("Error " + line.toString());
              }
              if(W){
                  System.out.println("Warning " + line.toString());
              }
              if(C){
                  System.out.println("Compliance " + line.toString());
              }
          }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Ruby version which you can easily adapt to Java :

```
current_prefix = ""

ARGF.each do |line|
  regex = /^(Errors|Warnings|Compliance|Instructional)\s*-/
  m = regex.match(line)
  if m then
    new_prefix = case m[1]
                 when 'Errors' then 'Error'
                 when 'Warnings' then 'Warning'
                 when 'Compliance' then 'Compliance'
                 when 'Instructional' then 'Instructional'
                 end
    current_prefix = new_prefix
  else
    puts "#{current_prefix} - #{line}"
  end
end
```

Sample invocation

```
$ ruby myconfig-parser.rb sample.txt
Error - The cake is a lie 
Error - All things have endings
Error - Twinkies are back
Warning - Show me the money
Warning - Metric > Imperial
Warning - food for thought
Warning - derp derp derp
Compliance - Space is disease and danger wrapped in darkness and silence.
Compliance - Khaaaaaaaaaaan!
Instructional - I'm a doctor, not an escalator.
```

I hope that helps.